# Naming Conventions for parameters in C#

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

Consider this code:

```
private static Call AddLog(NewCallEventArgs ev, Call callParam)
{
    var call = new Call
    {
    }
    return call;
}
```

I have a **Call** param in parameters  and I have a **Call** object in code.

What is the best naming-conventions for this situation?

Comment: I often use one letter local variables, such as `var c = new Call()` - But there's a chance I'm not normal..

Comment: I do the same thing as Mike: use one-letter for local variables. But that just proves how subjective and opinion-based this question is. Not a good fit for Stack Overflow, unfortunately. The voting on answers would work just like a poll.

Comment: `var _call = new Call();` or `var aCall = new Call();`. Still depends on you

Comment: @CodyGray stack overflow has naming-conventions tag

Comment: Most of those questions are either mistagged, already closed, or begging to be closed. It's what we call a "honey pot". If you want to earn some janitorial-related badges, you could go through and flag most of the questions there as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: "Not a good fit for Stack Overflow, unfortunately. The voting on answers would work just like a poll."  -- I agree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This really depends on your own preference and what the objects represent.
One clear example is if you have a before and after scenario (previous and next) the convention should be

```
private static Call AddLog(NewCallEventArgs ev, Call previousCall)
{
    var newCall = new Call
    {
    }
    return newCall;
}
```

It is somewhat hard to answer this without knowledge about your domain. Personally I like to give my variables names that clearly illustrate what the variable is used for

Answer (score 2):

`callParam` is redundant, and since C# has a `params` keyword, I wouldn't call it that.

you can use `myCall` or `callCopy` or something else that is specific to your use case.